# How can I use SoundCloud as a source of podcasts

Tags: podcasts, soundcloud

I have played around a little with SoundCloud as a listener. On the other hand I have quite a lot of experience of using podcatchers. First I used Itunes and synced to an ipod. Then I went to android and have used applications such as doggcatcher and beyondpod and my latest favorite: Pocket Casts. How can I create a RSS feed out of what I am following on SoundCloud so that I can use Pocket Casts to follow? Can I?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.
My guess is soundcloud doesn't / can't allow it, as users don't have permission to download all tracks.

Comment: @jamesmstone according to [soundcloud's help center](http://podcasting.help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/2106990-setting-up-your-podcast-s-rss-feed), soundcloud uploaders have the ability to create an rss feed for their podcasts. However I can't find a feed on  https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange so either the help is out of date, or stack exchange didn't create a feed yet.

Comment: I found that SE does indeed have a feed for their soundcloud podcast that works with my podcatcher (podlisten), at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264228/stack-exchange-podcast-feed-gone/264230#264230 . I don't know how you get that directly from a soundcloud podcaster. More detail at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113447/stack-exchange-podcast-episode-28-download-blues

Answer (score 1):

You can use a site like [SoundCloud Playlist Downloader](http://scdownloader.net/playlist-downloader) if you're looking to get all of your podcasts from one playlist downloaded.

As far as an RSS feed in Pocket Casts, it definitely is possible according to [this guy's website](https://www.r-podcast.org/posts/update-on-podcast-feed-situation.html). It looks like he took an RSS feed URL from his user profile.

Answer (score 1):

Both [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) and [Zapier](https://zapier.com) has integrations to SoundCloud, and can trigger an event when someone you follow uploads a new track.

You can try one of them and combine 2 or more steps to create your rss feed from your updates.

For example, Zapier has an option to create an RSS feed, which might work for you!